# Как убрать заголовок окна QML

Tags: qt5, c++11, qtcreator, qml, qt4

Создал приложение Qt Quick в QtCreator. Мне необходимо убрать заголовок окна с названием и кнопками закрыть, свернуть.

Нашел информацию, как убрать заголовок в приложении с классом окна MainWindow. Для этого необходимо в конструкторе MainWindow установить флаг `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`. Не могу понять, как установить этот флаг, если мое окно создается через

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
```

Или может быть в приложении с QML это делается иначе?

Буду рад, если поможете мне с этим вопросом.

Файл `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true

    width: 1280
    height: 900
    title: qsTr("Browser")
    ...
}
```

Файл `main.cpp`, который сгенерировал QtCreator:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 900
    title: qsTr("Browser")
 
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint // <-
```